# /dev/HAX is missing every time I restart my computer

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, intel

It was all good until a few weeks ago, when I tried to open AVD from Android Studio, and it said HAX is not installed, as shown below:

[image: HAX missing]

I went to the extras folder for Android sdk, and reinstalled HAX it says it is already installed, And it would work after a reinstallation, as shown below:

[image: already installed]

BUT!! BUT!! Every time I shutdown my laptop, and restart it, it would tell me that /dev/HAX is missing, again! Every time. How can I solve this problem?

Specs:
Macbook Pro Early 2015,
El Cap,
Android Studio 1.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem on my Mac running El Capitan.
For some reason, the /dev/HAX device is removed after reboot or after sleep.

I have found this command to work inserting the module back into the kernel:

```
sudo kextutil /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext
```

Just run it from the terminal.

It does not solve the problem, but at least it doesn't require a complete reinstall of the haxm module.

Comment: After sleep?  That's just unacceptable.  How is this not a huge development issue - or is it?